# Load, crop and save jpg C++

Tags: c++, macos, image-processing

I want to made a function in C++ who will receive a jpg file and a array of coordinates.
Then crop it, using the coordinates, the save the new image as a new jpg.
Try to use imagemagick but can't compile it at macosx.
Need help please.

Comment: that the problem i don't have any code, even to know how to start it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OpenCV it is the most powerfull and easy to understand tool with a great documentation. It already has loads of algortihms implemented and ready to use.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Answer (score 0):

I would use the library FreeImage:

http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago i used: http://www.catenary.com/howto/crop.html#C_source, but I don't know if it compile in OS X.

Comment: hi thanks but i think to victor image processing library you have to buy it or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it:

Use a libaray to do it for you, try [JUCE C++ Library](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It has specific classes to do this for you. No need to compile, just link it.

The other approach is to do it yourself. You need to first convert JPEG to raw data - a really tough task - load it to your structure and then doing the processing.

I will not recommend second approach if it is for commercial purposes but if you want to do it for fun, try second approach with BMP file. It will be super fun!

Comment: thanks shobhit, i think i will the first one, lol not enough time to the second approach maybe one day